# Scala Boolean to String conversions

Tags: scala, casting, type-conversion

One way to convert `true: Boolean` onto a String is

```
scala> true.toString
res: String = true
```

However,

```
scala> true.asInstanceOf[String]
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Why the latter attempt fails ?

Many Thanks

Comment: The first way isn't a cast, it's a method defined on the `Boolean` type.

Comment: @LimbSoup ok, thanks, updated question formulation accordingly :)

Comment: it's because `Boolean` is not a subtype of `String`.

Comment: Possible duplication of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686992/scala-asinstanceof-with-parameterized-types

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `Boolean` isn't a subtype of `String` or type compatible with `String`

```
scala> val a: Any = "Hello"
a: Any = Hello

scala> val b = a.asInstanceOf[String]
b: String = Hello

scala> val c: Char = 123
c: Char = {

scala> val d = c.asInstanceOf[Int]
d: Int = 123

scala> (123).asInstanceOf[Double]
res0: Double = 123.0

scala> (1.3).asInstanceOf[Int]
res1: Int = 1
```

As you can see, I can easily cast any type compatible types back and forth, in this case numbers (including chars) are cross compatible. All types are compatible with `Any`, because `Any` just holds any arbitrary object reference, so as long as you "unbox" using the right types, you're golden.

```
scala> val arr = Array("Hello", 245, true)
arr: Array[Any] = Array(Hello, 245, true)

scala> val first = arr(0).asInstanceOf[String]
first: String = Hello

scala> val second = arr(1).asInstanceOf[Int]
second: Int = 245

scala> val third = arr(2).asInstanceOf[Boolean]
third: Boolean = true
```

This works fine, and as long as you're careful with how you unbox, you won't get any errors. This is how you'd do it in Java before generics were introduced to the language. That said, if you cast any one of the array elements to the wrong type, you'll get the cast exception.

The `.toString` method is different from a type cast, in that it's not a cast at all, it exists to serve as a concise way of converting any object, to a string representation of itself.

```
scala> val a = List(1,2,3,4)
a: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> a.toString
res0: String = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

This is done so that any type can be printed if necessary, and has nothing to do with casting.

Answer (score 0):

When invoking toString on primitives, scala compiler automatically performing boxing (putting primitive to object wrapper) and then performing toString method on Boolean object:

```
public String toString() {
        return value ? "true" : "false";
}
```

while invoking asInstanceOf means casting from Boolean to String, these are different types, so CCE is thrown.