# Scala: refer to nested type of class, which comes as type parameter to generic

Tags: scala

I want to implement class, which describes action about setting some option value. I want to make option 's value type be depent of option type. I am trying to make this:

```scala
case class SetOptionMessage[T <: BaseOptionType](
    option: T
    value: Option[T#ValueType]
)

abstract class BaseOptionType {
    type ValueType
}


object SomeBooleanOption extends BaseOptionType {
    final type ValueType = Boolean
}
```

But when I am trying to use that classes like this:

```scala
val msg = SetOptionMessage(SomeBooleanOption, Some(true))
```

I got compilation error:

```
Error:(15, 43) type mismatch;
found   : Some[Boolean]
required: Option[?#ValueType]
SetOptionMessage(SomeBooleanOption, Some(true))
                                      ^
```

How can I proper refer to nested type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Type member

```
case class SetOptionMessage[V, T <: BaseOptionType{ type ValueType = V }](
  option: T,
  value: Option[V]
)

val msg = SetOptionMessage(SomeBooleanOption, Some(true))
// msg: SetOptionMessage[Boolean,SomeBooleanOption.type] = SetOptionMessage(SomeBooleanOption$@2e93ebe0,Some(true))
```

### Implicit evidence

```
case class SetOptionMessage[V, T <: BaseOptionType](
  option: T,
  value: Option[V])(implicit e: V =:= T#ValueType)

SetOptionMessage(SomeBooleanOption, Some(true))
// SetOptionMessage[Boolean,SomeBooleanOption.type] = SetOptionMessage(SomeBooleanOption$@2e93ebe0,Some(true))

SetOptionMessage(SomeBooleanOption, None)
// SetOptionMessage[SomeBooleanOption.ValueType,SomeBooleanOption.type] = SetOptionMessage(SomeBooleanOption$@2e93ebe0,None)
```

### Different parameter groups

You can't use `case class` with this solution.

```
class SetOptionMessage[T <: BaseOptionType](option: T)(val value: Option[T#ValueType])

val msg = new SetOptionMessage(SomeBooleanOption)(Some(true))
// SetOptionMessage[SomeBooleanOption.type] = SetOptionMessage@7f216e0c

msg.value
// Option[SomeBooleanOption.ValueType] = Some(true)
```

### Unsafe class cast

Don't use it.

Comment: Thank you, it is working. Could you give me a documentation link to read more about this technique?

Comment: @ArturEshenbrener: unfortunately I can't. I guess I saw this kind of code in answers of [Miles Sabin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/146737/miles-sabin?tab=answers), though I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

`ValueType` is a path-dependent type. That means you can't access it using `#`, which can only refer to non path-dependent types.

Try changing `SetOptionMessage` to:

```
case class SetOptionMessage[T <: BaseOptionType](val option: T,
                                                 private val _value: Option[Any]) {
  val value = _value.asInstanceOf[Option[option.ValueType]]
}
```

However, you should not use this solution (check note below). I am keeping the answer undeleted to expose its problems.

**NOTE**

As @senia indicates in his answer, this is the worst solution since it relies on class cast. This cast presents some limitations as the highlighted  in this SO answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6690611/1893995

The expression:

```
val msg = SetOptionMessage(SomeBooleanOption, Some("hello"))
```

will not only compile but it won't even crash at runtime.

Comment: @senia You are right. In fact, it suffers from the Scala's limitation highlighted at http://stackoverflow.com/a/6690611/1893995
But I'd like to keep the answer precisely for exposing that problem.

Comment: It's unsafe and will fail at runtime instead of compile time on `SetOptionMessage(SomeBooleanOption)(Some("a"))`. You should not use class cast at all. And you don't have to. See `Different parameter groups` from my answer.

Comment: It's not about `scala`'s limitations. It's about unnecessary class cast.

Comment: @senia The Scala's limitation is that, at runtime, the code `val msg = SetOptionMessage(SomeBooleanOption, Some("hello"))` does not throw an exception. I agree with your comments on the hazards of using cast.