# Scala placeholder in array for pattern match

Tags: arrays, scala, pattern-matching

I want to match a Array whose first element is 0 or 1 or Null, below is the example:

```
def getTheta(tree: Node, coding: Array[Int]): Array[Double] = {
    val theta = coding.take(coding.length - 1) match {
        case Array() => tree.theta
        case Array(0,_) => getTheta(tree.right.asInstanceOf[Node],coding.tail)
        case Array(1,_) => getTheta(tree.left.asInstanceOf[Node],coding.tail)
    }
    theta
}
```

the tree class definition is :

```
sealed trait Tree

case class Leaf(label: String, popularity: Double) extends Tree

case class Node(var theta: Array[Double], popularity: Double, left: Tree, right: Tree) extends Tree
```

Actually I know that Array(0,__) or Array(1,_) is wrong, but what I care about is only the first element of the Array, and how can I match it?

Can someone help me?

Comment: Avoid using asInstanceOf as not safe

Comment: Thanks! @Cyäegha, I didn't see that question before, actually it is the same to my problem.

Comment: usually you should return Option[Node] and then use patterns matching to see what result is

Comment: Thanks, I will modify it and one more question, why asInstanceOf is not safe?

Comment: Here is some comments on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686992/scala-asinstanceof-with-parameterized-types As per my understanding asInstanceOf just will throw an exception if object is Null and this is not "idiomatic" way of dealing with objects:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use varags in Array to achieve this.

```
coding.take(coding.length - 1) match {
   case Array(0, _ *)  => getTheta(tree.left.asInstanceOf[Node],coding.tail)
   case Array(1, _ *)  => getTheta(tree.right.asInstanceOf[Node],coding.tail)
   case Array() =>  getTheta(tree.right.asInstanceOf[Node],coding.tail)
}
```

Other options are

- converting Array to list

  ```
  coding.take(coding.length - 1).toList match {
    case 1 :: tail => getTheta(tree.right.asInstanceOf[Node],coding.tail)
    case 0 :: tail => getTheta(tree.left.asInstanceOf[Node],coding.tail)
    case Nil =>  getTheta(tree.left.asInstanceOf[Node],coding.tail)
  }
  ```
- use if guards in pattern match as below

  ```
  coding.take(coding.length - 1) match {
      case x if x.head == 0 => getTheta(tree.right.asInstanceOf[Node],coding.tail)
      case x if x.head == 1 => getTheta(tree.left.asInstanceOf[Node],coding.tail)
      case Array() =>  getTheta(tree.left.asInstanceOf[Node],coding.tail)
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks a billion, convert into List is a excellent choice.

Comment: use @_* => Array(head, tail @_*) insted of converting array to list